# What is the difference between single and double quotes?

Tags: javascript, string

What is difference between `'string'` and `"string"`?

For example, I use

`alert('abc')` and `alert("abc")`

`document.getElementById('id')` and `document.getElementById("id")`

I don't see any difference.

Comment: Because there is no difference. It's only a problem of conventions.

Comment: Thanks! i thought there is some difference, like in obj-c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between them in javascript.

It is used to escape from escaping the quotes by using the alternative.

Like:

```
'some string "some here"';

"some string ' some here'";
```

You don't need to escape them using `\` as in most language.

Comment: Working hard to get "[more good reps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228020/what-is-considered-as-good-reps)" I see :P

Comment: @Lix, nah. I shouldn't have asked that question ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference in **JavaScript**. Other languages handle single and double quotes differently. For example, with PHP, you can use double quotes to perform variable substitution.

One thing that *might* be relevant is the [JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) spec](http://www.json.org/) in which all strings should be wrapped with **double** quotes. Most languages will be able to handle both types of quotes in the same manner, but if you need to have a 100% valid JSON object then you'll need to use double quotes.